# CSS for Table not being applied right?

Tags: html, css, html-table

http://jsfiddle.net/RpCTx/4/

The table columns aren't changing to the width I specified. The second column is way to narrow...

css:

```
body{
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica;
}
th {
     border-bottom: 1px solid black;   
}
.product_name, td {
    width: 132px;
}
.description, td + td {
    width: 290;
}
.quantity, td + td + td {
    width: 30px;
}
.list_upfronts, td + td + td + td {
    width: 77px;
}
.sales_price, td + td + td + td + td{
    width: 76px;
}
```

html:

```
<strong>
    <u>
        Starcraft, or something
    </u>
</strong>

<table id="integration_and_data_services">
    <tr>
        <th class="product_name">
            <b>Product Name</b>
        </th>
        <th class="description">
            <b>Description Information</b>
        </th>
        <th class="quantity">
            <b>QTY</b>
        </th>
        <th class="list_upfronts">
            <b>Upfronts</b>
       </th>
        <th class="sales_price">
            <b>Sales Price</b>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Le Product name</td>
        <td>Lots of text here about whatever the product is about. Just needs to wrap to multiple lines.... Probably should be about starcraft... whatever.</td>
        <td>1.00</td>
        <td>$4500.00</td>
        <td>$4500.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the `px` off your `width` declaration for the 2nd column:

```
.description, td + td {
    width: 290px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/RpCTx/5/)

Answer (score 2):

Just have the width address each th

You do not need them in the tds. remove the td +...

Like so, http://jsfiddle.net/RpCTx/8/

Comment: +1 gutierrezalex, I completely ignored that fact in getting the issue fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a mistake in the rule: you lack the 'px'

This is correct:

```
.description, td + td {
    width: 290px;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad the internet exists... but this mistake is embarassing =\

Comment: **it happens :D (to anyone, me included)